# Why is Snowflake date filter on current_date() slower than on to_char(current_date())?

Tags: sql, date, filter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem**

When I query a large table in Snowsight using the `current_date()` function in my date filter, like

```
select * from large_table where dt = current_date() - 1
```

the runtime is 12m 32s. However, when I use `to_char` on the `current_date()`, like

```
select * from large_table where dt = to_char(current_date() - 1)
```

the runtime is 25s. These were executed at the same time, with the second completing first. This makes me believe that caching is *not* the issue.

My question is: what is going on to cause this runtime difference? And to zoom out, are there principles of date filtering performance that I should be aware of in Snowflake?

**EDIT: Profiles added**

I'm unsure why one scan had more partitions than the next, but it is the exact same query except for the `to_char` portion

**Query 1 - Overall Profile**

[image]

**Query 1 - Profile of Largest Table Scan**

[image]

**Query 2 - Overall Profile**

[image]

**Query 2 - Profile of Largest Table Scan**

[image]

Comment: what is data type of `dt` ? it seems to be char since you dint mention. This means, for first SQL, SNF has to convert  to date automatically while comparing. In second SQL, SNF doesnt have to do anything so its faster.

Comment: Please provide query profiles for both queries: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile

Comment: Did both queries give the same results?  Comparing dates and strings directly like that can create situations where you get unexpected results.

Comment: `dt` is a VARCHAR(16777216) is appears to be. So, essentially, if we do `to_char(current_date())` it will convert the date *once*, but if we just use `current_date()` it has to convert between datatypes many times? Is that what's going on @KoushikRoy?

Comment: Also, @LukaszSzozda, the profiles are added!

Comment: yes, no one can compare date to a char. so, it converts the column from table to date and then do the comparison. You can do same activity for a small table and you will see the difference between char vs date will be negligible. Because its a large table, auto-conversion is taking time.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is: Why doesn't Snowflake do what *I* did and recognize the datatype is different and then convert `current_date() - 1` to `to_char(current_date() - 1)`? In that case, the performance of query 1 should be the same as for query 2, right?

Instead, what is it doing? Why would it take so much longer? It must not be converting `to_char` just once, but many times. Why? Does that make sense @KoushikRoy?

Comment: Snowflake probably decided to convert the left-hand side to date to match the data type of the constant on the right. Could be due to data type precedence that says, on type mismatch, the lower precedence data type (varchar is one of them) should be converted to higher precedence data type (date is one of them). I couldn't find a documentation for Snowflake, but here is one for SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The point is-don't be at the mercy of implicit cast if you are comparing to a constant. Either explicitly cast the constant or use matching data types for comparison

Comment: Very helpful @Radagast. If anyone wants to write an answer, I'd be happy to accept something that consolidates all this!

Comment: i dont think its snowflake probably decided, most DBMS does this. DBMS doesnt know the type of data user is going to input so it changes data of the table as per users's input. Because end of the day, users input prevails than anything. We need to know about this behavior before using non matching data type.

Comment: Definitely. I think it's a little dangerous if they do this without clear guidance on the best methods in their own docs.